# яндекс карта, перемещение за указателем мышки

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Как реализовать навигацию по яндекс карте так, чтобы перемещаться по карте можно было бы просто подводя мышку к краю области карты? Версия api 2.1 интересует. Я видел там есть какой-то метод который изменяет цент карты, но как передвигать её не нашел. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: ну вот этим самым методом и передвигать, вот только что будут делать пользователи мобильных устройств?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, мобильные устройства нас не интересуют, только десктоп. Можете пример показать, как сделать событие подведения мышки к краю экрана и получения её текущих координат?

Comment: да, вот только доберусь до компа :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, буду признателен)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, основанный на сдвиге центра карты, условия выглядят чуть убого, можно придумать формулу поизящнее, но это пусть останется за рамками данного ответа.

```js
let size = 50;
let maps = [map1, map2];

ymaps.ready(e => {
  map("map1", 60, 30);
  map("map2", 49, -123);
  addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMoved);
  addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
});

function map(id, lat, lon) {
    window[id]._instance = new ymaps.Map(id, {
        center: [lat, lon],
        zoom: 11,
        controls: []
    });
}

function onMouseOut() {
 maps.forEach(map => {
   map.dataset.speedX = 0;
   map.dataset.speedY = 0;
 });
}

function onMouseMoved(e) {
  let x = e.x, y = e.y;
  maps.forEach(map => {
    let r = map.getBoundingClientRect();
    let d = map.dataset;
    
    d.speedX = 0;
    let matchY = y > r.top && y < r.bottom;
    if (matchY && x > r.x && x < r.x + size)
      d.speedX = -1;
    if (matchY && x > r.right - size && x < r.right)
      d.speedX = 1;
      
    d.speedY = 0;
    let matchX = x > r.left && x < r.right;
    if (matchX && y > r.y && y < r.y + size)
      d.speedY = 1;
    if (matchX && y > r.bottom - size && y < r.bottom)
      d.speedY = -1;
  })
}

setInterval(changeCenter, 10)

function changeCenter() {
  maps.forEach(map => {
    let d = map.dataset;
    if (+d.speedX || +d.speedY) {
      let coords = map._instance.getCenter();
      coords[0] += (+d.speedY)*0.001;
      coords[1] += (+d.speedX)*0.001;
      map._instance.setCenter(coords);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
} 

#map1, #map2 { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map1"></div><div id="map2"></div>
```

Comment: Шикарно, огромное спасибо!